# Storing 'shared' items MongoDB in application with RESTful API

Tags: api, mongodb, authentication, schema

I am creating an application in which users can share articles.

Currently, when a `user` shares an `article`, it adds the `article` ID of the shared item to an array called `shares` on the `user`.

```
var userSchema = {
  // `sharedItems` is a list of article IDs that the user has shared
  sharedItems: { type: Array }
};
```

However, because I need a way to query the shared items for multiple user IDs (similar to a news feed sort of query), I decided to go down the route of creating a separate collection just for shared items.

```
var shareSchema = {
  // The ID of the user who shared the article
  userId: { type: String },
  // The ID of the article shared
  articleId: { type: String },
  dateCreated: { type: Date }
};
```

To tie this together in my application code, when a `user` is updated, there is a check for whether or not the `sharedItems` array on the `user` was updated – if it is, a task is delegated to the `shares` collection to add or remove any matches respectively. I have done this because, when a user shares an item, my client-side application only has to worry about making a `POST` request to the `user` resource, rather than making a `POST` to the `user` *and* `share` resources. The trouble here is that I am relying on replication, and I worry that for various reasons, there could be some inaccuracies.

The need for the `sharedItems` array on the `user` entity is because, when any articles are loaded, my application must detect which items have been shared by the logged in user. My application parses the response for each loaded `article` and checks whether or not the current `user` has that `article` ID in its `sharedItems` array – if it does, it adds a property of `isShared` to the article.

The only other alternative to achieving all of this — that I can think of — would be to remove the `sharedItems` array from the user schema, and add some sort of authentication to my API, so that `GET` requests to the `article` resource will be aware of who the current user is, and thus, my back-end can worry about checking whether or not the current user has shared the `article` that is sent in the response, instead of doing the parsing on the client-side.

The trouble I have with this is that I do not want my API to require authentication. Articles should be accessible to all users, logged in or out (`GET` on the `article` resource). However, I only want logged in users to be able to share articles (`POST` to the `share` resource, or currently a `POST` to the `user` resource which delegates creation/deletions of share documents).

How would you handle this in terms of MongoDB collections and schemas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a `shareCount` field in the `GET /article` resource (to prevent unauthenticated exposure), and then use an asynchronous (and authenticated) API call to `GET /user` that you can use to mark articles as shared after the initial load.

If you do this, your `GET /article` resource doesn't need to do any additional work behind the scenes, and every request will get the same information (with `shareCount`). Only when a user is logged in will your design even care to mark anything as shared.

Comment: The trouble with storing a list of shares items on the `User` model is that MongoDB has a maximum document size of 16MB, and so — whilst it is unlikely a user will ever reach that many shares — it is a bad design decision to store unlimited-in-size arrays on 'schemas' in MongoDB. Users can also mark items as read in the application, and in my application, it is very likely that a user will have read many hundreds of thousands articles after some usage. Can you talk about how you would circumvent this problem?

Comment: Are you sure that is a legitimate concern? If you're using the normal Object ID, which is 12 bytes, then we're talking somewhere in the ballpark of ~1.3 million IDs before you would hit that maximum. If your user used your application for 10 years, they would need to share 350+ articles a day, every day, for 10 years before they would hit that limit.

Comment: That being said... it doesn't affect my suggestion all that much if you decide to use a ``shareSchema``. The "meat" is that you reserve the work to decide what is shared after the fact -- asynchronously -- and use a simple counter in the ``GET /article`` resource.

Comment: I've got you! Do you think MongoDB is a good choice for this data model? I've also got things like "users can follow users", which has issues such as "how many users does this user have following them?"

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother to keep the `sharedItems` in the `userSchema` if you are worried you cannot keep them in sync.  Just keep the `sharedSchema` up-to-date.   It doesn't seem like it should be a secret who has shared an article, so you can can include the current user ID in the request to GET the article without authentication and have the back-end tell you if the specified user shared the article.

If you want to try to keep the sharing information secret, then you you could add optional authentication to the GET article API and only return sharing information about the authenticated user but return the rest of the article information regardless of authentication.  Or you can build the `sharedItems` array on the back end from the `sharedSchema` when you request the `user` information and include it in the response.